# Inserting Cart Products into Multiple Tables Only Inserts the 1 latest product of cart

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I want to insert the content of the cart into multiple tables.. It is inserting but the problem is that it only inserts 1 product from my cart. but the content of the cart has 3 items.
I am using Crinsane/LaravelShoppingCart.

How can i insert products A,B,C into multiple tables?

CartController@checkout

[image]

Items from Cart

[image]

Comment: and question is  ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - Please read our guide about how to ask questions. Never post code as images, copy/paste it here and format it as code. If you don't edit your question, you'll get downvoted quite fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the variables inside for loop:

```
$transactions = [];
$transactions_solds = [];
$transactions_prods = [];


foreach(Cart::contents() as $c) {
$transaction = new Transaction();
$sold = new TransactionsSold();
$prod = new TransactionsProd();

// Rest of code

array_push($transactions, $transaction);
array_push($transactions_solds, $sold);
array_push($transactions_prods, $prod);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! you're a life saver.